# How to remove circular dependency between two classes in a same package?

Tags: java, design-patterns, circular-dependency

We are doing some refactoring and we have hit the wall here. 
There are two service classes AService and BService doing different works have a circular dependency.
Earlier they were in a different libraries so there was no circular dependency existed. But now after refactoring we have moved them into a single library into a single package.
AService job is to persist some data into a NoSQL database for a separate use case.
BService job is completely different than AService job.
AService needs BService to GET some data.
BService needs AService to write some data to NoSQL Database and reads back.

How to fix the circular dependency issue with making each of them depends on each other. Any design pattern for such issues?

```
class AService {
@Autowired
private BService bService;

}

class BService {
@Autowired
private AService aService;

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could move the AService code that requires BService to BService and have AService as just a service for writing to the datastore.

Comment: Perhaps your services are too big, and do too much? Consider having more but smaller, simpler services.

Answer (score 5):

The real question is why your conception making A and B dependent of each over?

- It could be that A and B represent the same concept, and may be merged.
- It could also be that a part of your service A or B should be extracted in a new service C.

In that last case you need to know which method depends on which service, and which one could be extracted in a new service. Without having the context and the list of methods it's difficult to propose a solution.
In the case of indirect recursive methods, you may have to cut also some methods.

Side note: don't try to find a workaround to make it work with circular dependencies, it shows a conception problem, you have to do the refactoring.

Comment: AService and BService are working for separate use case. They should'nt be into a single library but because of some other issue with networking calls we have to merge them so that they can call each other.
So we cannot merge them as concept is different.
Extraction wouldn't make sense as both represents different concepts.

Comment: @AvinashKharche You have to understand that the fact that multiple classes depend on each other indicates that they're sharing common responsibilities (they complement each other) or they depend on shared information (operation). You have to evaluate your class design using the Single Responsibility Principle. You will have to rewrite your classes and introduce new ones. Looking at the Mediator Pattern can also help you.

Comment: @AvinashKharche You're right that merging is not the solution (Single Responsibility Principle). But extraction of common code _does_ make sense and _does not_ change concepts. In your special case all you have to do is to extract the database accesses to a new class: `DatabaseConnector`. This class is responsible for reading and writing to the database and impplements all CRUD operations. Now instead of depending on each other, both services depend on `DatabaseConnector`?

Comment: @AvinashKharche If you still refuse to accept your design flaw, you can introduce interfaces to lift the circular dependencies. Look for Dependency Inversion Principle.

Comment: @AvinashKharche See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 (recommended):**
the redesign of class responsibilities. Adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle and according to the class details you revealed, we can fix your class design by extracting at least one new class: the `DatabaseConnector`. This class encapsulates all database related operations (CRUD) and therefore lifts the circular dependency of the service classes (without changing the original conceptions of the classes).

```
// This is just a raw template to express the intention
class DatabaseConnector {
  void createInDatabase(Object data) {
  }

  Object readFromDatabase(Object args) {
  }

  void updateInDatabase(Object data) {
  }

  void deleteFromDatabase(Object data) {
  }
}

class AService {
  @Autowired
  private DatabaseConnector dbConnector;    
}

class BService {
  @Autowired
  private DatabaseConnector dbConnector;    
}
```

You can add more specialized methods to the `DatabaseConnector` to meet special requirements (e.g. `readName()`, `readId()`, etc).

Since it is likely that more classes will need to access the database in future, you already solved or prevented new circular dependencies today. Encapsulation solved potentially upcoming problems.

**Solution 2:** dependency inversion

```
interface IAService {    
}

interface BService {
}

class AService implements IAService {
  @Autowired
  private IBService bService;    
}

class BService implements IBService {
  @Autowired
  private IAService aService;    
}
```

A circular dependency is always an indicator for bad class design. In most cases the origin is the violation of the Single Responsibility Principle (the *S* in SOLID). A wrong composition concept can also lead to this design error. What will always help, but not fix the conceptional flaws of class responsibilities, is the introduction of interfaces to invert all dependencies (the *D*  in SOLID). Taking the SOLID Principles serious can safe a lot of time and work and will always lead to better code (although you introduced higher code complexity).

The Mediator Pattern can also help to lift circular dependencies by encapsulating the bidirectional interaction of two or more objects.

The downside of your current code is (besides the circular dependency), that whenever class A changes and also data persistence changes, you have to touch and modify class B. This changes can break class B which is using the same persistence operations. This is true for all cases where one class has shared responsibilities with another class. If there wasn't the shared code, both classes wouldn't know each other at all. In your special case, where the dependency is cyclic, you add this flaw to the other dependency direction as well: whenever B needs to adjust or extend how to read data then you have to modify class A, which might break A. If you are using unit tests, then you would have to refactor the tests of *both* classes too. This tight (and cyclic) coupling of A and B will lead to errors or bugs. Extending code has become dangerous. But the good news is that circular dependencies never compile (since the dependency resolution leads to infinite recursion).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to move the method that Service B uses out of Service A and into Service B OR into a completely different class.

The design indicates that you probably have too many methods in Service A which Service A does not actually use, but which are public methods that should really be static and in another Class entirely.

Comment: Moving shared code from one class to the other will solve the problem but doesn't improve the design. The operation(s) where not part of the one class for no reason. Adding it will also add responsibility that wasn't obviously intended. It can also defer the cyclic problem until the code is extended and a new classes will need this functionality too. If you keep it real with the Single Responsibility Principle you are always safe when introducing new classes.

Comment: So the answer is not "make code static" but "encapsulate shared code (or shared responsibilities)". Encapsulation would require to introduce a new class that takes care of the shared responsibility.

Comment: That is true, I suppose you can also create an Abstract class which is implemented by both Service A and Service B and move common methods to the Abstract class.

Comment: To make both services inherit this abstract base class? This would introduce new problems and a relationship between the services that isn't natural: a service type _is_ a database connector. It would be more natural to design it like: a service _has_ or _uses_ a database connector. Composition over inheritance. This way you can change the concrete implementation of the database connector even at run time. Inheritance would require to rewrite or to change the base class(es) to swap in a different connector. You then have to adjust every place in code where you referenced the old base class.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I guess I misunderstood Service A and Service B as both being similar classes which touch the SQL Database and which have overlapping methods but you're basically saying that there should be a single class called "SQLDatabaseConnector" (or something of the sort) in which both Service A and Service B use and which if necessary Service A and Service B could override.

Comment: Yes both are services that depend on database. There might be more services that also depend on the database too. When each service has it's own implementation to access the database, then you would have to change a lot of code, when you want to migrate to a different database. You would have a lot of duplicated code as well. To circumvent this problem you'd give all service classes a  parameterized constructor that would take an `IDatabaseConnector`, which they can use without knowing any details about the database itself.

Comment: Today we pass in a `SqlDatabaseConnector`, but tomorrow we can easily change it to `MySqlDatabseConnector` without modifying the service classes, since they only know `IDatabaseConnector`, which both connectors implement. Inheritance can't do that. If every service class inherits from `SqlDatabaseConnector`, then you have to modify and redeploy each service to make inherit the `MySqlDatabaseConnector` and change all base class references and unit tests as well. If there are more shared methods beside the database access, then I would introduce another class(es) to encapsulate this methods.

Comment: If you don't know the Repository Pattern I recommend to read about it. It's perfect as it helps you to decouple services from the underlying database.

Answer (score -3):

Try to put the autowired on setter instead:

```
@Autowired
public void setServiceB(ServiceB service){
 this.serviceB = service;
 }
```

Comment: This might fix the error of the dependency injection container (Spring), since the setter dependencies are now satisfied _after_ the instance is constructed. But this doesn't fix the design flaws of the dependency graph itself. Therefore this is not a solution to the original problem but a hack to trick the IoC framework.